# How to use a key in hash for a value for another key

Tags: perl

I have one hash there I have two key, I want to use one key as a value of another key. Is it possible in Perl?

exp:

```
%hash= (
        abs =>[a,b,c,e];
        xyz=> abs
      );
```

I tried but was not able to do this.

Comment: It's trivial (and indeed, your code does so) to assign a key as the value of another key. I suspect that you want to assign the same value referenced by one key to another key, so that both keys reference the same value.

Comment: @chepner There's also the possibility that he misunderstands the importance of quoting, and the built-in function `abs` is giving him a 0. Without warnings, he does not understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever value you wish as a hash value, including the name of another key. You can not, however, fail to quote the value, as it is not automagically quoted like the keys:

```
my %hash = (
    abs => 'foo',
    xyz => 'abs'
);
```

Quoting a parameter preceeding `=>` is optional, if it does not contain spaces. Quoting the parameter following it is not.

You might also be interested to know that

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

will produce warnings, if you have warnings turned on (which you always should).

```
Unquoted string "a" may clash with future reserved word at
Unquoted string "b" may clash with future reserved word at
```

The reason this still "works" is -- as far as I know -- for backwards compatibility, and you should always quote your strings. Furthermore, case in point, your bareword `abs` is actually mistaken for the built-in function [`abs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/abs.html), which in this case will try to find the absolute value of `$_`, and probably fail, returning 0 (and issuing a warning about undefined value in `$_`).

What your array ref should look like is this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Or with a simpler syntax, using the `qw()` operator:

```
[ qw(a b c d) ]
```

You might also note that semi-colon `;` is not a valid character inside an assignment to a hash. The key/value pairs inside the parentheses shall be delimited with commas, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply using a wrong syntax. Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# warnings and strict are ALWAYS a good idea in perl code
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = ( 
        abs => ['a', 'b','c','e'], # make strings clear and use a comma, no semicolon
        xyz => 'abs'
);
```

And if you want your hash printed out, just to check it, `Data::Dumper` is useful - especially once you have a bigger hash:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

then, this should work:

```
my %hash = (
    abs => [ qw(a b c) ],
    xyz => 'abs',
);

print $hash{ $hash{xyz} }[0];

# prints 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that while the hash is being defined, it is anonymous. Not until the entire list is parsed is it assigned to `%hash`, so there's really no way to reference earlier parts of the hash while it is being defined. There are a couple of workarounds available:

```
my $common_lref = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'];
my %hash = ( abs => $common_lref, xyz => $common_lref );
```

or

```
my %hash = ( abs => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'] );
$hash{xyz} = $hash{abs};
```

In both cases, changing the array referenced by `$hash{abs}` changes `$hash{xyz}`, and vice versa.

Note: This only works if the value is a reference (as it is here), and only it only works as long as you don't change `$hash{abs}` or `$hash{xyz}`. You can still change the elements of the array referenced by `$hash{abs}` and `$hash{xyz}` (including adding and deleting elements).

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't compile.

Here's a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my %hash = ( 
        abs => ['a', 'b','c','e'],
        xyz=> 'abs'
      );

print "abs: @{ $hash{$hash{xyz}} }\n";
```

First, use `use warnings; use strict;`

You have to quote your value at `xyz =>`. Side note: `abs` is also a perl built-in.

You also need to quote your anonymous array value at `abs =>`:

```
Eg, `[ qw(a b c) ]` or `['a', 'b', 'c',]`.
```

Then in the print, I dereference(`@{}`) the value, as it is a `list`.